# Why does the object shake, fly and fall apart in Unity 3D and how to fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics, physics-engine

I recorded the  [video of the problem](https://youtu.be/VmwvaCdZtUg)

I am trying to build a robot simulation. It is supposed to walk using joints.
I am following the process from [this article](https://www.hadarak.com/blog/learn-a-quadruped-robot-how-to-walk-using-reinforcement)

But the model is not working as it should and I don't understand why. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the object/fbx. Try to remove all useless components to its children. If it doesn't works, try selecting "Freeze Position" and/or "Freeze Rotation" of all x, y and z axis in the rigidbody

Answer (score 0):

The Mass on your RigidBody from the inspector that i see is 0.001.
You will need to set the masses of the actual components, like they've set it to 20 in the Article. Fix the RigidBody settings and everything should work fine in this case, without the need for any advanced physics settings changed.